# Styling for Form Fields when using FormDataConsumer

Tags: react-admin

I'm trying to follow the example here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#hiding-inputs-based-on-other-inputs

The problem I have is that I'm trying to hide multiple fields at once:

```
<FormDataConsumer subscription={{ values: true }}>
    {(args: any) => {
        if (!args.formData.type) return null;
        else if (/system$/.test(args.formData.type)) {
            // It's a system account
            return <TextInput source="username" {...args} />;
        } else {
            // It's a standard user account
            return (
                <>
                    <TextInput source="email" {...args} />
                    <PasswordInput source="password" {...args} />
                    <TextInput source="fullName" {...args} />
                </>
            );
        }
    }}
</FormDataConsumer>
```

When I do this, the fields under the fragment render in a single row like this:

[image: One Row Only]

How do I match the styling of the other form fields when hiding and showing multiple fields?

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way would be to try this out...

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const customStyles = makeStyles({
  input: { display: 'block' }
  // other styles
});

const MyForm = props => {
  const classes = customStyles();

  return (
    <FormDataConsumer subscription={{ values: true }}>
      {(args: any) => {
        if (!args.formData.type) return null;
        else if (/system$/.test(args.formData.type)) {
            // It's a system account
            return (
               <TextInput 
                 source="username" 
                 className={classes.input} 
                 {...args} />
            );
        } else {
            // It's a standard user account
            return (
                <>
                    <TextInput 
                      source="email" 
                      className={classes.input} 
                      {...args} 
                    />
                    <PasswordInput 
                      source="password" 
                      className={classes.input} 
                      {...args} 
                    />
                    <TextInput 
                      source="fullName" 
                      className={classes.input} 
                      {...args} 
                    />
                </>
            );
        }
      }}
    </FormDataConsumer>
  )
}
```

So the underlying concept is as follows:

- Create your custom stying
- Pass this style to each element via the `className` prop that's available to `Inputs` and `Fields`

**PS:** After you test out a couple of styles, it's always advisable to move them into a separate `.js` file. Better to keep your styling separate from logic.